# Master Sliders swipe and href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sliders

I have this code for sliders.

```
<div class="ms-slide slide-<?=$i++;?>" data-fill-mode="fill" data-delay="5" >
<img href="<?=$sliders->slide_resim;?>" src="<?=$siteurl;?>/img/blank.gif" data-src="<?=$siteurl;?>/uploads/sliders/<?=$sliders->slide_resim;?>" alt="Hilbet110.com">
</div>
```

when i put href before img tag sliders not working. when i put onclick in img inside its open page on swipe. what can i do for this? if swipe dont work link if only click go to link. can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Old subject without answer so here is mine.

The `href` attribute does nos exist for `img` tag.
If you want to add a link on an image, try one of these :

- add an `<a>` tag around it, with your `href` attribute
- use *Javascript* as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics)
- use jQuery to create a callback `$('#your_id").click(function () { window.location = 'www.google.com'; });`

That's all folks !